# JavaScript code outputs twice when clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, the code in the example below keeps outputting twice when clicking the button and I can’t figure out the cause.

```js
var onClick = function() {
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  var rows = "";
  rows += "<tr><td> " + cars[0] + " </td></tr>";
  $(rows).appendTo("#list tbody");
};

$('#button').click(onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
<table id="list" class="table table-bordered; sortable">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th>Group Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thread>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/785/).

Comment: Your fiddle code is different from your snippet.

Comment: @Xufox I just corrected it thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because you have a typo: `<thread>` should be `<thead>`.

This typo caused your table structure to be invalid, making the browser attempt to correct it to this:

```
<thread></thread>
<table id="list" class="table table-bordered; sortable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Group Name</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Thereby, your `<table>` had *two* `<tbody>` elements, making the `"#list tbody"` selector yielding *two* results, thus appending it twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your table thead has typo. I fixed it in this updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/786/).

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
         <table id="list" class="table table-bordered; sortable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Group Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
```